# How to execute prepared SQL statement stored in another table

Tags: sql, string, stored-procedures, teradata

Suppose we have a **Teradata** table `db.queries` in which prepared statements are stored in `statement_code` as CLOB, for example the content of such field can look like:

```
INSERT INTO DATA.TABLE
(ID, JOB_NAME, DATE)
VALUES(1, 'TEST_JOB', CAST(CURRENT_DAY AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')='$currentDay');
```

We have a stored procedure, which reads this data and then executes this using the following code:

```
  SELECT statement_code
  FROM db.queries
  WHERE ACTIVE_FLAG = 1
  INTO SQL_QRY;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_QRY;
```

This is failing because the extracted statement_code in the SQL_QRY has now esacped single quotes.

```
Syntax error, expected something like '')'' or '','' between a string or a Unicode character literal and the word ''YYYYMMDD''.
```

Returned string from SQL_QRY is:

```
INSERT INTO DATA.TABLE
(ID, JOB_NAME, DATE)
VALUES(1, ''TEST_JOB'', CAST(CURRENT_DAY AS DATE FORMAT ''YYYYMMDD'')=''$currentDay'');
```

As opposed to the stored `statement_code`:

```
INSERT INTO DATA.TABLE
(ID, JOB_NAME, DATE)
VALUES(1, 'TEST_JOB', CAST(CURRENT_DAY AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')='$currentDay');
```

We have tried using `OREPLACE` in the variable setting to no avail. The function can replace double single quotes to any character, but single quotes.

By dumping various testing combinations:

```
OREPLACE(SQL_QRY, '''''', '*')  --replaces to *
OREPLACE(SQL_QRY, '''', '*')    --replaces to *
OREPLACE(SQL_QRY, '''', '')     --get rids of quotes completely
OREPLACE(SQL_QRY, '''''', '''') --leaves the double quotes
```

Is there a way to overcome this nuisance or what is the proper way to achieve the goal? Retrieve prepared statements and execute them?

Kind Regards

Comment: Can you show the actual string returned in `statement_code`?

Comment: how about you do this? : `PREPARE stmt1 FROM SQL_QRY;
   EXECUTE stmt1;`  do you still get the same error?

Comment: @dnoeth Edited to question with returned string.

Comment: @eshirvana Tried that as well with no change in the behaviour.

Comment: Your 4th OREPLACE should work, but #2 should replace to '**'. Return the SQL_QRY as an output variable from your SP, copy/paste and try to run. Why do you insert those statements with doubled quotes?

Comment: @dnoeth Sorry, I have misread. That is the thing. I have no control over the `statement_code` - this is where this is stored as a valid SQL syntax with single quotes. Within the procedure, after loading these into the `SQL_QRY` it is converted to double single quotes.

Comment: SELECT INTO does *NOT* escape / double the quotes in a returned string value. Perhaps whatever you are using to display the returned value is doing that. Assuming the quotes are not the issue, your SQL_QRY above is not valid. You can't supply a logical expression  `CAST(CURRENT_DAY AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')='$currentDay'` as a column value.

Comment: @Fred Thank you, Looking deeper into supplied query, I have located the odd bits that are causing this. In my live example there is missing a single quote in the reffered chunk of code concerning the casting conversions on one instace.

Comment: @dnoeth Returning the SQL_QRY has helped to identify this, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Since your query is prepared already, I think you don't need to `prepare` it again, execute immediate converts ' to '' to make a string ready as a SQL statement to be executed and screws your already prepared string up.

So you just need to do :

```
EXECUTE SQL_QRY;
```

or if your queries stored with two single quotes maybe you need to convert them to one single quote:

```
OREPLACE(SQL_QRY, '''', ''')
```

Comment: Executing directly without the `IMMEDIATE` returns Error 5526: Referring to undefined statement.

Comment: ok maybe I'm wrong. on the second thought how about doing this : `OREPLACE(SQL_QRY, '''', ''')    -- convert two single quotes to one single quote

Comment: Yes, this was my aim, as suggested in the fourth example, had to escape the single quotes tho. But with no luck. I am definitely doing something odd.

Comment: no you are are removing all the quotes , I;m replacing them with one single quote